# Looking for Ubuntu 14.04 Photo Viewer just like Eye of MATE

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, mate, multi-touch

Some context: While using Ubuntu MATE 16, I liked using the standard image viewer, Eye of MATE. It enlarges the picture by using a two-finger swipe up. IT will scroll left and right by using arrow keys. To move to the next picture, tab to the Previous button and use the right arrow key to move to Next, hit Enter. It might sound like a bit of a process but it is very efficient when using the keyboard, much faster than dragging a photo with a cursor.

On Ubuntu 14.04, is there a way to Eye of Gnome to scroll left and right without using the cursor to move the picture? I am enlarging the picture so that it is larger than the window it is in. The scrolling problem would be solved by using a two-finger swipe left or right but that also enlarges and shrinks the picture.

The pictures are of a book so I can read it and do the programming examples without having to use the large book.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

It turns out that with a little more exploring the keyboard using the default Ubuntu 14.04 image viewer, Eye of Gnome, I figured out how to move around the photo using the keyboard. I checked the Eye of Gnome app homepage and found no instructions, even after searching their Github page. So, I do not feel so bad about posting such a rudimentary question.

Anyway. again, the problem is viewing a photographed book. Photos of books generally need to be enlarged when viewing on a computer. Eye of MATE operates better in some respects but I am now using Ubuntu 14.04.

Enlarge photo: double finger swipe up:
Reduce photo: double finger swipe down
Maximize window: double-click header bar at top of window
Scoll left/right: Shift-Ctrl-trackpad double swipe up/down (who woulda thunk it, I know, I know - the developers of EOG)
Scroll up/down: Shift-Ctrl-trackpad double swipe left/right
Scroll through previous/next photo: keyboard cursor keys left/right and/or up/down